# Setting an image in a UIImageView inside a table view cell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I download some images using an `NSThread`. When all the images are downloaded, I have to put them in `cell.myimageview`. Give me the solution for setting an image in a user-defined method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    TableCell *cell = (TableCell *)[TableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[TableCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }


    NSString *bedsbaths=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Beds:%@ Baths:%@",[[AppDeleget.statuses valueForKey:@"beds"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],[[AppDeleget.statuses valueForKey:@"baths"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.mlsno.text=[[AppDeleget.statuses valueForKey:@"mlsno"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.price.text=[[AppDeleget.statuses valueForKey:@"price"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.address.text=[[AppDeleget.statuses valueForKey:@"address"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.bedsbaths.text=bedsbaths;
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
return cell;

}
-(void)LoadImage
{
    for(int x=0;x<[ListPhotos count];x++)
    {   
        NSData *imageData =[ListPhotos objectAtIndex:x]; 
        id path = imageData;
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
        NSLog(@"%@",url);
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(downloadDone:) withObject:img waitUntilDone:NO];
    }

}
-(void)downloadDone:(UIImage*)img {

    // I have to set the cell here. How?        
    cell.myimageView.image=img
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the containing view controller

Under the method tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: when creating a new cell, ad the code:

`cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed@"name of image.png"];`

Answer (score 0):

As long as you keep a reference to the cell, it's not too hard.  I'd go about it like this:

```
- (void)downloadDone:(UIImage*)img {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:yourCellRow inSection:yourCellSection];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // now you have the cell you wish to modify;
    cell.myimageView.image=img;
    [myTableView reloadData];
    // if you would prefer, you could also call [myTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]
    // if you only want to reload that specific cell;
}
```

Comment: I just tested this and it worked fine for me.  I used `cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testImage.png"];`, but it is the same idea.  Try setting up a log statement when `downloadDone` that says something like `NSLog(@"image is %@", img);` to make sure the image exists.  My guess is that the image either doesn't exist or is getting released before you can set it (which we can fix later after we figure out what is going wrong)

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are able to set it in the `downloadDone:` method, you will face a problem later because of reusable cells. So the right place for setting the image would be the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` itself. So how do you load the images? Save them in an array or a dictionary. Say the count doesn't change, we can use an `NSMutableArray` object to store count number of `NSNull` singleton objects and later,

in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
if ( [[images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isMemberOfClass:[UIImage class]] ) {
    cell.myImageView.image = [images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

in `LoadImage`

```
for(int x=0;x<[ListPhotos count];x++)
{   
    ... 
    [photos replaceObjectAtIndex:x withObject:image];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(downloadDone:) 
                           withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:x];
                        waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

in `downloadDone:`

```
- (void)downloadDone:(NSNumber *)row {

    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[row intValue] inSection:0]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have set image to the Image view in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method itself. Try the below code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    TableCell *cell = (TableCell *)[TableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[TableCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }


    NSString *bedsbaths=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Beds:%@ Baths:%@",[[AppDeleget.statuses valueForKey:@"beds"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],[[AppDeleget.statuses valueForKey:@"baths"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.mlsno.text=[[AppDeleget.statuses valueForKey:@"mlsno"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.price.text=[[AppDeleget.statuses valueForKey:@"price"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.address.text=[[AppDeleget.statuses valueForKey:@"address"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.bedsbaths.text=bedsbaths;
    NSString *filePath = [self getImagePath];
    UIImage * img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    cell.myimageView.image=img;
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    return cell;

}
    -(NSString *)getImagePath
    {
      /*here you can get the path of your image here*/

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
UIImageView *logoImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 55)];
logoImgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 [cell.Imageview addSubview:logoImgView];
 NSMutableArray *arrChng = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 [arrChng addObject:logoImgView];
 [arrChng addObject:[Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(setImagesAfterShow:) withObject:arrChng];


-(void)setImagesAfterShow:(NSMutableArray *)array
{
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[array objectAtIndex:1]];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImageView *img = [array objectAtIndex:0];
img.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
[pool release];
}
```

this method used for loading images in backend so it's easy to smooth scrolling of table

One more method using ASIHTTPRequest in which the images are loading in backend and it's very good to use check out the [link](http://geekios.wordpress.com/2011/08/28/how-to-load-images-in-backend-in-iphone-part-2/?preview=true&preview_id=65&preview_nonce=98e5681a3c). It may be useful to you.